Octree as struct not class
I was wondering (as I could not find any implementation online),
if anyone here would have an idea of how to create an octree as a struct and not a class.
The problem is that Octrees are usually recursive, and structs cannot have auto-inheritance.
So, the code:
public struct MyOctree
{
    public MyNode RootNode;
}

public struct MyNode
{
    public MyNode[] SubNodes;
}

would cause a cyclic reference error (nodes contain nodes).
I'm trying to implement such a structure for GPU usage, and any Nullable data (e.g. a class) throw a not-supported exception on the GPU initializer.
Thanks.

I find it extremely hard to believe that you couldn't find any C# Octree online, since I have found several in the past, myself. Did you search github.com?

I have implemented Octrees and KdTrees in the past, some of my implementation are on Git.... The question is not there. It is on the "struct" aspect

First off, that code compiles just fine. Which means you haven't even tried to compile it, you're just guessing "in the dark" so to speak. Please, at least try your code before posting here.
Secondly, if you're implementing this for GPU, struct with internal array works very differently.
C# is a (memory) managed language, so it works primarily with references, not at all like unmanaged languages as are for example used for GPU shader languages. In your example, we have a reference to an array (which is 4-8 bytes) stored inside MyNode. In this way, the compiler can calculate the sizeof your struct accordingly, even though the array itself is of a variable size, it is stored in another piece of memory, not inside the struct -- again, only a reference to the array is stored inside the struct.
It is because the array is separate, that your struct code can work at all (in spite of your guess).
In performance terms: we need to perform a double pointer de-reference every time we access MyNode.SubNodes[n] -- one deref to jump to the start of the array's memory block, and another deref to jump to the element in question. This is costly, and is among the primary reasons why C# is often slower than unmanaged languages (C, C++, etc.) which allow single derefs.
In C, HLSL, GLSL, etc., struct is a completely different animal. (At least for a contiguously allocated struct without double dereferencing) The array is actually allocated within the struct. We must know the full / maximum size of array in advance, or else the compiler cannot get sizeof MyNode and cannot compile the code. In C, for example:
struct MyNode 
{
    public MyNode[8] SubNodes; //we specify the maximum size. This along with the other members is used to calculate the struct size.
    
    public int anotherMember;
    public byte someOtherMember;
}

Note that the above struct can be achieved in C# with the fixed and unsafe keywords -- but I strongly recommend you never do that! C# without memory safety is like a bird without wings.
What you actually want though, is to allocate it all in one, and pass around array indices:
//this assures that the *entire* octree is allocated in one contiguous chunk of memory (fast).
struct MyOctree
{
    public MyNode[MAX_NODES] nodes; //Root should be at [0].
}

struct MyNode 
{
    public int parentNode;
    public int[] subNodeIndices; //indexes into MyOctree.nodes
}

This kind of struct setup is much faster, because all the memory is allocated together (locality of reference), and there are fewer cache misses as a consequence.
IIRC, HLSL doesn't(?) have an easy way to do this... you're just passing around fixed length buffers (with lengths specified for DirectX or OpenGL on the CPU side) and have to recast them to treat parts of them as arrays. I could be wrong though, the last time I used HLSL was some years ago.

Thanks for the time and the elaborate answer.
I did try it, though i did not use a MyNode array, juste a MyNode. Error was :
"Struct member 'MyNode.Right_child' of type 'MyNode' causes a cycle in the struct layout"
It is interesting that by using an array no such error occurs...

@LChougrani If you're getting a compiler error, you should be including that specific information in your initial question.

Did you intend for subNodeIndices to be of type int[8]? Otherwise, the suggested code doesn't make any sense (and it's not valid C#), as subNodeIndices would still be a reference to a managed array on the heap (so the the entire octree would not be allocated in one contiguous chunk of memory).

But declaring fixed-size arrays directly inside a struct should be possible with the inline arrays feature of C# 12+

@Ghost4Man Good suggestion... however assuming Unity, it doesn't yet support that.
